# How to find the usage of IDs in an Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a (hopefully) simple problem: I got tons of XML-files for the different pages shown on the handy.

I got tons of different .java-files as well. This stuff is pretty much undocumented and I have no idea where what id's from buttons, containers etc. are used in the code.
My idea was to copy the id out of the xml-designer and look for it in the project. But: Where is the option to look in the entire projekt for some words?

I can't use "Find Usage" (nothing happens there for god knows reason), and find would only let me look in the specific file I have open at the time. Is there something like "Find in project" as it is in monodevelope?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think your idea will work. For example, you can have two layouts, `my_layout_one.xml` and `my_layout_two.xml`, which each have `TextView` elements _with the same id_ (`@+id="textView"`). Searching for that id in the code will give you all of the instances where _either_ of the `TextView`'s are referenced.

Comment: What is the problem with finding which `Activity` or `Fragment` uses which layout file, then going from there?

Comment: i think if you press Control btn and click on the variable you want, it will show where the variable was first initialized

Answer (score 9):

You can do a full search (using various scopes, including project wide) using **Find in Path**. It provides just about any kind of searching you can think of :)

To reach it:

- Use `Ctrl+Shift+F` (on Windows).
- On the main menu `Edit -> Find -> Find in Path...`.

Highlighted text in the editor will automatically be added as the `Text to find`.

The dialog looks as follows:

[image: Find in Path]

You can use the `Options` to narrow the search and the `Scope` to limit (or broaden) the area to search in.